# Weak 'H', Pullup on inout bidirectional signal in simulation

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

Is there a way to tell the simulator (I'm using Modelsim) to pull a signal to weak 'H' when it's not being driven by either bidirectional interface?

For example if I have an I2C signal I2C_SDA that is declared as an inout from 2 modules.  One is my actual UUT and the other is a testbench.  Both have statements like this:

```
io_i2c_sda <= r_I2C_DATA when r_I2C_DATA_EN = '1' else 'Z';
```

So both ends are tri-stated.  This works fine in simulation, except that the line is BLUE ('Z') all the time that neither end is transmitting.  How can I pull-up this line to a 'H' in the code when neither end is transmitting?

Comment: Is that actually what will happen in the actual hardware, or are you beautifying your testbench? :)

Comment: It's a test bench simulation of the pullup resistors normally present on an I²C bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For VHDL, it should be possible to simply add an extra driver to the signal (which has to be of std_logic type), with the constant value 'H'. In Verilog one would use a simple '1' driver and the net type `wand` for wired and. 'H' specifically means a weak high driver, so it will be overridden by the low drivers.

Comment: Yes, in VHDL simply add a continuous assign in the test bench using `io_i2c_sda <= 'H';` of type `std_logic`.  The resolution function of `std_logic` will then result in final signals value of `'H'` when the other drivers are `'Z'`, and `'1'` if one of the other drivers are `'1'`.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that you could do that.  Thanks @MortenZdk.  To clarify for anyone else reading this, if you map the two together via a wire, let's call it w_I2C_SDA, you can also assign this wire via a combinational assignment.  w_I2C_SDA <= 'H';  Now you have 3 drivers essentially, the UUT, the testbench driver (both of which are high-impedance when not driving) and the test bench combinational assignment w_I2C_SDA <= 'H', and the simulator is able to resolve all 3 of those.

Comment: if you're writing a tristate buffer, you may also want to make use of to_UX01(my_signal), which will perform strength reduction i.e. interpret H and L as '1' and '0' respectively.